# How do I speed up prediction using Python script

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, prediction

I need to provide very fast prediction which will be working in real time. Prediction itself takes very little time (0.003s), the only costly part in the script is loading a model (0.3 - 0.5s depending on the way I do this). The script must get way below 0.1s to be useful.

Part of the code I'm mentioning:

```
 model_path = 'single_tree.sav'
 model = joblib.load(model_path)
 document['some_key'] = whatever_feature
 prediction = model.predict(document)
```

How can I speed up this process without having this script running all the time? Is there any way to 'pre-load' the model?

Comment: Is this supposed to work as an API on the web? Why not just load the model once and have it wait for prediction requests?

Comment: you can pickle/unpickle it, or as has been said if you have som eapi store and retrieve it on demand

Comment: As @OferSadan says. Shove it into Flask, and replace your previous script with a HTTP request. You only load model once. (0.5s... lol... my scripts take 5-10 minutes to load the necessary data.)

Comment: This is a part of large application, prediction must be done while changing tabs in prompt. Efficiency is a key here. I made this question because I want to find a way to avoid having script running all the time and using API. Additionaly, communication through API takes time, while I have to cut everything I can.